# Update JS/JQuery variable based on the input of a html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have this javascript/ajax request for my advanced search page

```
     <script>
//      window.setInterval(function()
//      {
          $(function () 
          {
            var SearchTerm = '<?php echo $_POST['Search']; ?>';
            $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'Ajax/AjaxAdvSearch.php?SearchTerm='+SearchTerm, dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
                {
                $('#output').empty();
                    for (var i in rows)
                    {
                        var row = rows[i];          
                        var id = row[0];
                        var FunctionName = row[1];
                        $('#output').append("<a href='Page.php?ID="+id+"'>"+FunctionName+"</a><br>");
                    } 
                } 
            });       
          });
//      }, 5000);
      </script>
```

The `$_POST['Search'];` is obtained from a HTML textarea:

```
<textarea name='Search' style='width: 100%; height: 150px;'></textarea><br>
```

I want to dynamically update my javascript var each time the user types into the textarea, without the user having to press the submit..

so whilst the user is typing, the `var SearchTerm` is dynamically updated each time the textarea is updated with content.

Could anyone provide some assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .change() method in jQuery

```
var variableToUpdate = '';

$('#Search').change(function() {
    variableToUpdate = $(this).val();

    // call your search from within if you want
});
```

For search-as-you-type tutorials and plugins...

http://dbachrach.com/blog/2007/04/spotlight-like-search-as-you-type-with-css-ajax-js/
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/

Comment: Even better, use `this.val`

Comment: Even, even better, use `$(this).val();`

Comment: Giving it a try now, will this still work with my ajax request?

Comment: @user2146021  You'll have to get more creative than that.  You'll have to figure out a way to handle each concurrent call (you might want to consider figuring out a good way to manage that).  My answer simply resolves your original question, not this new one :)

Comment: Could you provide an example to point me in the direction for this solution

Comment: and @DavidL this is not appending to #output when i do: `$('#output').append(variableToUpdate);`

Comment: @user2146021  Surely you don't want to append the search input?  Since that's what you have at that point...

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you an example

```
<html>
<head><style>

</style>

<script>
var DataCon;

function UpdateDIV(){
    document.getElementById('updater').innerHTML=DataCon;
}
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="updater"> 
</div>

<textarea onkeydown="DataCon=this.value;UpdateDIV()"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

And here you can see, as you type a global variable updates and along with it, to check its working a UpdateDIV function also given which updates the div with id updater...

Now just assign certain vars and get your job done